# como importar el nombre de una imagen de un json file y ponerlo en la ruta con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

cuando hago lo siguiente no me aparece la imagen en la pagina

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={require(`../../assets/bot/${item.Image}`)} className="imgcard" />
```

Comment: EL json tiene el nombre de la imagen y estoy tratando de crear un catalogo de de tarjetas y cada tarjeta tiene su propia imagen la cual tomo e nombre de json file y la idea es que el tome la especifica imagen de la ruta que parece en el codigo

Comment: Por qué necesitas `require` para un camino dentro de tu proyecto? `src={``../../assets/bot/${item.Image}``}` no funciona? (con solo un `)

Comment: no tambn probe sin el require y no funciona de esta forma src={`../../assets/bot/${item.Image}`}